# VS2022 showing unused suppression, but failing on build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm running visual studio, I taken latest code repository.
One method has `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage` attribute on it, on hover its showing unused suppression.
But while I build the project it throws error.

[image]

While building it getting this error(Method has ToLower() without and any culture).

[image]

I don't want any code change, because it's running code and someone already has added suppression over it.
Is my VS creating this issue, any help to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: The shown error is CA1305 but the supression is for CA1304

Comment: Oh my bad, Thank you I added this and it worked.

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? If you find the solution you can add your answer and it will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the suppressed numbers, they're `CA2000`, `CA1304` and `CA2202`. Your warning (that you chose to treat as an error) is `CA1305`, which is not part of the suppressed list.

> I don't want any code change, because it's running code and someone already has added suppression over it

Someone has added the wrong suppression numbers, probably copy & pasted. That's not quite the same.